# How to make a div always taking all height remaining and keep it scrolling on overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.main-div {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.bottom {
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
  overflow-y: unset;
  background: blue;
}

.table-panel {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.working-area {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.footer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="working-area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
          some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="table-panel">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>cell text</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer text</div>
  </div>
```

The main idea of the layout is to see 'table-panel' scrolling on overflow when using vertical resizing. But text wrapping for 'top' div on horizontal resizing is a requirement too. So if try to make 'top' div higher, 'bottom' div overlays the footer.

I would like to find out some way to make 'table-panel' scrolling on overflow without any side effects. I tried to use 'flex', but I'm not enough experienced in css so I haven't reached my goal - scrolling always is lost.

Is there some way to do it without js?

UPDATE: the exact result I would like to see, but without js https://jsfiddle.net/a4fay1r0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can use the column direction and play with the properties `grow` and `shrink`.

<sub>**Note:** I have removed some of your containers</sub>

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.main-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.working-area {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
}
.top {
  background: red;
}
.bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="working-area">
    <div class="top">
      some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but scrolling on bottom is lost and I can't get it back.

Comment: @GhfDllT what you mean by is lost ? This snippet works fine no ?

Comment: I need a scroll only on bottom div. In this snippen I see scroll on whole page, don't I?

Comment: Nop just on middle element @GhfDllT

Comment: sorry, I see it's working fine in chrome, but not in firefox, ie 11, or edge (browsers I need too).

Comment: Since you post you have tried flex I guess you know some prefixes for crossbrowser support, @GhfDllT try adding those prefixes http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: not sure I use proper prefixes, but It is working only in chrome and ie https://jsfiddle.net/a4fay1r0/1/

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you're looking for but if you change the `height` on the `.container` class to `calc(100% - 20px);` since your footer is locked at 20px it seems to fix the problem.

EDIT:
i noticed there was a problem with the resizing still. I've made `.container` and `.bottom` flex containers and made `.bottom` and `.table-panel` flex children with `flex: 1;` see updated jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g35ume3z/3/

Comment: Alternatively, if `calc()` is not an option, it should be possible to give `.table-panel` a `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` of 20px, then make the `footer` sit on top of it (absolute / relative positioning, z-index).

Answer (score 0):

[**CSS Grid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) Layout can do that now.

[**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) is now in most current browsers.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.container>* {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>HEADER</header>
  <div class="content">CONTENT
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure delectus iusto reiciendis nihil obcaecati expedita velit architecto ad! Cumque ex at accusantium illo ipsa tenetur reiciendis repudiandae quo, sint voluptate, eligendi libero assumenda
      animi in rerum! Quam quidem vero esse inventore a ab praesentium enim voluptatibus, vitae quae. Earum non provident, soluta dolor eius dolores accusamus, neque dicta vitae, deserunt, cum atque voluptates recusandae consequatur. Id sit nisi animi
      asperiores et reprehenderit dolore dolorum cupiditate distinctio, blanditiis mollitia temporibus saepe ipsa fuga odit quasi, dignissimos porro tempora libero, vitae perspiciatis autem ex aperiam quis. Hic eveniet at repellendus, sapiente. Molestias
      quaerat dolorem hic pariatur sunt aperiam, ea officia, laboriosam at vel reiciendis consectetur. Voluptate delectus ipsa doloremque, ratione eum. Eos in corporis rem aliquam! Unde consectetur, quo iure reprehenderit ex necessitatibus! Officiis iste
      aperiam explicabo cum, ipsum corporis optio voluptatum tenetur architecto fugiat sapiente fugit voluptatibus minus corrupti maxime minima nostrum consequatur! Temporibus vitae enim labore reiciendis natus est in doloribus velit dolor deserunt iusto
      pariatur quidem, omnis itaque possimus ratione, mollitia aperiam quod numquam, perferendis expedita. Corrupti dolor laboriosam quasi, dicta delectus, necessitatibus culpa saepe beatae fugiat non in architecto placeat alias! Accusamus iusto iste
      veritatis recusandae dolorum odio.</p>
  </div>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: looks close, will try